# Convert Unicode into Devnagari Font

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, static-libraries

I want to convert Devnagari unicode Words Like `मनोज`  to `dgf]h` as http://www.unicodetokantipur.hamrosansar.net/ convert using c#.
is there any library or api?

I google it but i cant find any solution.
i want functuon like

```
static sting ConvertUnicode(string Unicode)
{
    // Some code and logic
    return devString;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/grantcox/kantipurToUnicode does the conversion in the other direction. Maybe this is a start?